# I'm in the process of writing a Merge Sort program, I'm getting the following errors:

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge

Please consider the following code:

```
public class MergeSort {




public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] A = new int[10];

                // Printing the Initial Arrays
                     System.out.println("Array Elements before Sorting are as follows:");

                       for(int i = 0;i < A.length;i++){

                        System.out.println(A[i] + " ");
                                                      }

                        // Call the MergeSort Method here


                        // Printing Sorted Array here

                    System.out.println("Sorted Array are as follows:");

                    //for(int j = 0;j < result.length;i++){

                    //System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
                    //}


    public static int[] merge_sort(int[] B){

        if(B.length <=1){

            return B;

        }

        int midpoint = B.length/2;

        int[] left = new int[midpoint];

        int[] right;

        if(B.length % 2 == 0){

            right = new int[midpoint];

        }else {
            right = new int[midpoint+1];

              }

        // An Extra Array to store the result

        int[] result = new int[B.length];

        // Populating the array in the left array

        for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++){

            left[i] = B[i];

        }

        // Populating in the right array
        int x = 0;
        for (int j=midpoint;j<B.length;j++){

            right[x] = B[j];
            x++;
        }

        // Using recursion to divide the array in left and right again and again

        left = merge_sort(left);
        right = merge_sort(right);


    }// END OF METHOD merge_sort




}// END MAIN METHOD




}// END OF CLASS MergeSort
```

I'm getting the following error on the following lines in Eclipse: The cross sign indicates
error points in Eclipse:

X public static int[] merge_sort(int[] B){

Error says: Illegal modifier for parameter merge_sort; only final is permitted.

X   return B;

Error Says: void method cannot  return values. I have already defined method return type as an
integer array then why I'm getting this error?

X left = merge_sort(left);
X right = merge_sort(right);

Error Says: The method merge sort is undefined for the type MergeSort

Comment: Half of the problems are solved if you have a good indented code!

Comment: Is there any good tutorial to follow where I can learn indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you fix the indentation in your code the problem will be obvious. Your `merge_sort` method is declared inside your `main` method.

Just move the `}// END MAIN METHOD` closing brace onto the line above where you declare `merge_sort` and it should compile ok.

Comment: No problem - please consider accepting an answer if we helped to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have an method inside another method!

your `merge_sort()` method is inside `main` method!